# Underline and color URL in LuaLaTex

Tags: color

I was wondering how I can underline and color URL in LuaLaTex. I was able to add underline but could not change the URL and the underline to blue. Font is Calibri. Thanks!

```
% code used in LuaLaTex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

Further information can be found online (\underline {http://findsource.org/})

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example of what you've done so far. It's hard to provide specific advice without such information.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

Further information can be found online {\color{blue}\underline{\href{http://findsource.org/}{http://findsource.org/}}}

\end{document}
```

It uses `hyperref` package with options `colorlinks` and `urlcolor=blue`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another try, this time redefining the `\url`command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareUrlCommand{\url}{%
    \def\UrlFont{\color{blue}\normalfont}%      Adding a little color 
    \def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\underline{##1}}%  Underlining the url
    }


\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

Further information can be found online \url{http://findsource.org/}

\end{document}
```